# VBA Search for VLOOKUP in cells in range and Calculate

Tags: vba, excel

If one wanted to loop through cells and lookinto a formula for a vlookup and calculate one might do as follows:

```
Dim r As Range

For i = 1 To 100
    With wsSWM.Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each r In .Cells
            If Left(r.Formula, 8) = "=VLOOKUP" Then r.Value = r.Value
        Next r
    End With
Next i
```

However if one has vlookups nestled in between other calculations then one would want the ability to do find replace on VLOOKUP within a desired range but the replace portion would be the calculated lookup hardcoded.

ie

```
H4 + A10*VLOOKUP("This",A:1:B3,2,0)*A1/B2+C3 = H4 + A10*"lookupvalue"*A1/B2+C3
```

How would one go about completing this

Comment: Store the vlookup into a variable?

Comment: Sorry can please be clear on what is your problem and expectation

Comment: You can use InStr to find the character # that starts the VLOOKUP, then InStr again to find the character # for the closing parentheses for the VLOOKUP. You can use MID and REPLACE to the whole string with your calculated lookup. This is assuming there are no nested formulas in the VLOOKUP.

Comment: will the vlookup formula potentially have other formulas embeeded in it? or will it always be a straight `vlookup`?

Comment: @Tom - that was my thought, but if the `vlookup` has another embedded formula that will not work.

Comment: What do you plan to do if you hit a VLOOKUP returning an `#N/A` ?

Comment: or what if there are multiple vlookups in the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cover multiple vlookups in the formula, and will cover embedded formulas within the vlookup.  It will also simply use #N/A if there are any errors evaluating the vlookup:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sSecond As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sVLOOKUP As String
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim lOpenParenCount As Long
    Dim lCloseParenCount As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rFound = .Find("VLOOKUP", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
                If Left(rFound.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
                    Do While InStr(1, rFound.Formula, "VLOOKUP", vbTextCompare) > 0
                        sVLOOKUP = vbNullString
                        sValue = vbNullString
                        For i = InStr(1, rFound.Formula, "VLOOKUP", vbTextCompare) To Len(rFound.Formula)
                            sTemp = Mid(rFound.Formula, i, 1)
                            sVLOOKUP = sVLOOKUP & sTemp
                            Select Case sTemp
                                Case "(": lOpenParenCount = lOpenParenCount + 1
                                Case ")": lCloseParenCount = lCloseParenCount + 1
                                          If lCloseParenCount = lOpenParenCount Then Exit For
                            End Select
                        Next i
                        On Error Resume Next
                        sValue = Evaluate(sVLOOKUP)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If Len(sValue) = 0 Then sValue = "#N/A"
                        rFound.Formula = Replace(rFound.Formula, sVLOOKUP, sValue)
                    Loop
                Else
                    If Len(sSecond) = 0 Then sSecond = rFound.Address
                End If
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst And rFound.Address <> sSecond
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have ever gotten on stack exchange works great with absolutely no modification I really appreciate it!

Comment: this code without any modification is now evaluating sValue to "" because Evaluate returns Error 2042 or NA for every single value, have you any idea as to what could be causing that?? a highlight and f9 returns a value the sheet most definitely is working not sure why this is

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you will need to (1) Take the formula string; (2) Break out the portion related to Vlookup vs the portion[s] which relate to everything else, storing each as its own string variable; (3) Run the Vlookup portion 'manually' in VBA to find the value; and (4) Replace the formula in the cell with the vlookup value followed by everything else.

Because your check formula assumes that VLOOKUP will be at the beginning of the cell, this makes the process somewhat simpler, as we don't need to check for the 'other portion' being before the VLOOKUP.

My proposed code to perform these steps would be as follows [I have tested and confirmed that this works]:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim lookupString as String 'stores the portion of the formula which represents the Vlookup
Dim lookupValue as Double 'Stores the value of the lookup
Dim otherString as String 'stores the rest of the string
Dim formulaBrackets as Integer 'used to count how many brackets are contained within the Vlookup, to find where it ends

For i = 1 To 100
    With wsSWM.Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each r In .Cells
            If Left(r.Formula, 8) = "=VLOOKUP" Then 
                formulaBrackets = 0
                For j = 1 to Len(r.Formula)
                    If Mid(r.Formula,j,1) = "(" Then 
                        formulaBrackets = formulaBrackets + 1
                    ElseIf Mid(r.Formula,j,1) = ")" Then
                        formulaBrackets = formulaBrackets - 1
                        If formulaBrackets = 0 Then 
                            lookupString = Mid(r.Formula,2,j-1) 'picks up the string starting from the V in Vlookup [excludes the '='], up to the final bracket
                            otherString = Mid(r.Formula,j+1,Len(r.Formula)) 'picks up the string starting AFTER the ending bracket, to the end of thes formula
                            r.Formula = "="&lookupString 'sets up the formula in the cell to calculate the vlookup as written
                            lookupValue = r.value
                            r.Formula = "=" & lookupValue & otherString 'recreates the formula, having replaced the vlookup with its calculated value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                     Else
                         'No action required
                     End If
                 Next j

             End If
        Next r
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: And re-reading your question, I see now that some of my assumptions do not hold - nonetheless, you or someone else may get value by using this as a starting point to determine the placement of the Vlookup up to its ending bracket, and pickup the rest as necessary...

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party on this one, but here is my solution. It's not so different from the two already posted, but it did approach the problem from the idea of using a function specifically designed to extract the evaluated value of a LOOKUP in a function, and returns the altered formula in the function. That way, if you are looping through a range of cells, you can choose to call the function based on specific criteria, for example if the cell has a formula, or is hidden, or something like that.

Here's the function:

```
Function ExtractVLOOKUPValue(rng As Range) As Variant
'   This will extract the returned value of the first instance
'   of a VLOOKUP formula in a cell.

' Constant declarations.
Const sVLOOKUP      As String = "VLOOKUP"
Const lVLOOKUP_LEN  As String = 7
Const sOPEN_PAREN   As String = "("
Const sCLOSE_PAREN  As String = ")"

' Variable declarations.
Dim lVlookupPos     As Long
Dim lCnt            As Long
Dim lParenCnt       As Long
Dim sVlookupFormula As String
Dim sResult         As String

' Check first if the cell is a formula, and then
' if a VLOOKUP formula exists in the cell.
If rng.HasFormula Then

    lVlookupPos = InStr(rng.Formula, sVLOOKUP)
    If lVlookupPos <> 0 Then

        ' Isolate the VLOOKUP formula itself.
        For lCnt = lVlookupPos To Len(rng.Formula)

            ' Count the open parentheses we encounter so that we can use
            ' the apporpriate number of closing parentheses.
            If Mid(rng.Formula, lCnt, 1) = sOPEN_PAREN Then lParenCnt = lParenCnt + 1

            ' If we get to closing parenthese, start taking counts away from the
            ' parencnt variable so we can keep track of the correct number of
            ' parenthesis in hte formula.
            If Mid(rng.Formula, lCnt, 1) = sCLOSE_PAREN Then
                lParenCnt = lParenCnt - 1

                ' If we get done to zero in the parencnt, then extract the formula.
                If lParenCnt = 0 Then
                    sVlookupFormula = Mid(rng.Formula, lVlookupPos, lCnt + 1 - lVlookupPos)
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If

        Next lCnt

    End If

End If

' Now that we have the formula, we can evalutate the result.
On Error Resume Next
sResult = Evaluate(sVlookupFormula)

' If we errored out, return the #N/A in the function.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    sResult = "#N/A"
End If

' Replace the VLOOKUP in the formula with the result, then return it to the function.
sResult = Replace(rng.Formula, sVlookupFormula, sResult)

' Return the result, having replaced the VLOOKUP function.
ExtractVLOOKUPValue = sResult

End Function
```

And here's how you might call it:

```
Sub ReplaceFormulaWithValue()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each rCell In rng
    rCell.Formula = ExtractVLOOKUPValue(rCell)
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Ill give this one a shot as well, and see how it stacks up

Comment: The biggest problem with this code is that there is alot of wasted time by looping through all the cells vs searching in a range it is exponentially slower than the code I gave the correct answer too, but kudos for the indepth code and answer

Comment: Oh, no doubt about it. This version would only be useful if you wanted to take an action or set a criteria for use cell by cell, say for example you wanted to have it work on some cells and not others. But yes, the looping will absolutely be slower than the other solutions.